# About trap states when converting DFA to regular expression

Tags: regular-expressions

If we were to have a trap state in a DFA and we are converting it to a regular expression, how exactly would I incorporate that into the regex? Let's say our language only accepts a*, and my DFA has a start state/final state with a *a* loop, and once I get a *b* it goes into a trap. Would the regex simply be *a** meaning we ignore the *b*?

Comment: @DavidRicherby write it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, since the automaton can never accept after reading a $b$.